# Density of quadratic irrationals

Tags: real-analysis

This question from The Art and Craft Of Problem Solving by Paul Zeitz states:

> Show that the set of real numbers that are zeroes of quadratic equations with integer coefficients is dense.

How would I go about proving this? I have tried the following:

We need to prove that for a nonempty interval $(p,q)$, we have $a,c\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $$p < \frac{a+\sqrt{b}}{c} < q$$
Rearranging terms, we have
$$cp-a = m < \sqrt{b} < cq-a = n $$
Since $m, n\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sqrt{b}$ is irrational, by the density of irrationals in reals, our statement is proved.

Am I on the right track with this? Are there any errors?

Comment: The equations are fine but in the last line you are nowhere near done. $\sqrt{b}$ is not just any irrational number, this is a very specific set of irrational numbers, which is *not* dense in $\mathbb{R}$. You need to show that given $p$ and $q$ you can find $a, b, c$ such that this inequality holds and you haven't done that.

Comment: could you explain why it is specific? isn't it just any irrational number by definition?

Comment: Any irrational number? Can it equal $\pi$, for example?

Comment: ah, right. that was a bit dumb.

Comment: Already $\{ a + b \sqrt 2 : a,b \in \mathbb Z\}$ is dense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All rational numbers are zeroes of quadratic equations with integer coefficients(consider $q^2(x-p/q)^2$), since the rationals are dense, so are all such numbers.

Your proof is not correct, as noted by Qiaochu Yuan.

Comment: that's a nice solution.